# Can someone explain this behavior with Python?

Tags: python, integer, double

Can someone explain this behavior?

```
print("%.2f" % (model.x[1].value))
X = int(model.x[1].value)
print("%.2f" % X)
```

Output:

```
3.00
2.00
```

Thanks

Comment: What if `model.x[1].value == 2.9999` ?

Comment: Shouldn't 2.9999 prints as 2.99 for %.2f format? Does the format do rounding?

Comment: Nope & yup.  It’ll round up because the value is closer to 3.00 than to 2.99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `model.x[1].value` is less than 3 but >= 2.995 then when printed to 2 decimal places it will round up to `3.00`. But when you apply the `int` function it will be truncated to an integer of value 2, which will print as `2.00` when used with the `.2f` format.

```
>>> x = 2.994
>>> print(f"{x:.2f}")
2.99

>> x = 2.995
>>> print(f"{x:.2f}")
3.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. The value is indeed not an integer. I was fooled by a mixed integer nonlinear programming solver. It seems that it doesn't round the solution to integer by itself.